# I am getting this error (AnalysisException: path dbfs:/mnt/Abinandhana/Mart/Dimension/dimCustomer_parquet already exists.)

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

```
if not os.path.exists('/mnt/Abinandhana/Mart/Dimension/dimCustomer_parquet'):
    Customer_Mart.write.parquet('/mnt/Abinandhana/Mart/Dimension/dimCustomer_parquet')
else:
   

  df2 = Customer_Mart
  df1 = spark.read.parquet('/mnt/Abinandhana/Mart/Dimension/dimCustomer_parquet')


  merged_df = df2.alias("t2").join(df1.alias("t1"),(col("`t1`.`SourceSystemId`") == col("`t2`.`SourceSystemId`")), "left") \
.select(
    col("`t2`.`CustomerId`"),
    col("`t2`.`SourceSystemId`"),
    coalesce("t2.AccountNo", "t1.AccountNo").alias("AccountNo"),
    coalesce("t2.AccountStatus", "t1.AccountStatus").alias("AccountStatus"),
    coalesce("t2.AccountDesc", "t1.AccountDesc").alias("AccountDesc"),
    coalesce("t2.PrimaryGroupNo", "t1.PrimaryGroupNo").alias("PrimaryGroupNo"),
    coalesce("t2.PrimaryGroupDesc", "t1.PrimaryGroupDesc").alias("PrimaryGroupDesc"),
    coalesce("t2.Customer", "t1.Customer").alias("Customer"),
    coalesce("t2.CustomerGroup", "t1.CustomerGroup").alias("CustomerGroup"),
    coalesce("t2.DateOpened", "t1.DateOpened").alias("DateOpened"),
    coalesce("t2.DateClosed", "t1.DateClosed").alias("DateClosed")
)
  display(merged_df)


 merged_df.write.mode("overwrite")\
.parquet('/mnt/Abinandhana/Mart/Dimension/dimCustomer_parquet')
```

If the path is already present acc to the code it should enter into else block and proceed why is it erroring out

Comment: What write `mode` are you trying to implement, is it `append` or `overwrite` ?

Comment: if there is no file i want to write the file in parquet format. if there is a file i want perform merge and overwrite it in the same location. please help me.

Comment: Azure Databricks

Comment: @AbinandhanaG - Per your comment, you can just try to use `option("mode", "overwrite")` in the 1st step itself. What is the point of redoing it in else block, presuming your data in `Customer_Mart` is the same.

Comment: if a new file in placed in the source location with some changes, when the code in run for the second time i want to update the changes and then write it in the location('/mnt/Abinandhana/Mart/Dimension/dimCustomer_parquet')

Comment: In that case write, the best way to identify the root cause is to implement `if-else` part separately in a small code block and check where exactly is it going wrong. May be a simple print statement should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment. I got the same error.**

[image]

To resolve this issue, you need to include the `/dbfs/` path in your file path `/dbfs/mnt/Abinandhana/Mart/Dimension/dimCustomer_parquet`. when you are checking whether a file directory exists or not.

**Sample code:**

```
import shutil
import os
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, coalesce

if not os.path.exists('/dbfs/mnt/Abinandhana/Mart/Dimension/dimCustomer_parqueta1'):
    df.write.parquet('/mnt/Abinandhana/Mart/Dimension/dimCustomer_parqueta1')
else:
    
    df2 = df
    df1 = spark.read.parquet('/mnt/Abinandhana/Mart/Dimension/dimCustomer_parqueta1')

    merged_df = df2.alias("t2").join(df1.alias("t1"),(col("`t1`.`SourceSystemId`") == col("`t2`.`SourceSystemId`")), "left") \
    .select(
        col("`t2`.`CustomerId`"),
        col("`t2`.`SourceSystemId`"),
        coalesce("t2.AccountNo", "t1.AccountNo").alias("AccountNo"),
        coalesce("t2.AccountStatus", "t1.AccountStatus").alias("AccountStatus"),
        coalesce("t2.AccountDesc", "t1.AccountDesc").alias("AccountDesc"),
        coalesce("t2.PrimaryGroupNo", "t1.PrimaryGroupNo").alias("PrimaryGroupNo"),
        coalesce("t2.PrimaryGroupDesc", "t1.PrimaryGroupDesc").alias("PrimaryGroupDesc"),
        coalesce("t2.Customer", "t1.Customer").alias("Customer"),
        coalesce("t2.CustomerGroup", "t1.CustomerGroup").alias("CustomerGroup"),
        coalesce("t2.DateOpened", "t1.DateOpened").alias("DateOpened"),
        coalesce("t2.DateClosed", "t1.DateClosed").alias("DateClosed")
    )
    display(merged_df)

    merged_df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet('/mnt/Abinandhana/Mart/Dimension/dimCustomer_parqueta1')
```

**Successfully executed the code without an error:**

[image]